# Can you pass the customs/passport control if you are drunk?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, alcohol

Can one pass the customs or passport control drunk?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: Define "drunk".

Comment: In control I would believe yes, but if your breath smells or you walk unsteady then I would think no, considering drunk passengers might create a ruckus while in the air.

Comment: If I can recall, you work in the cabin crew, right? Can the airliner refuse to board you if you are too drunk?

Comment: @AyeshK no, unless you are a threat to the aircraft or passengers.

Comment: One more Jack and coke. Tall. Quick, my flight departs in five minutes.

Comment: @AyeshK If I hear one more pilot say that...

Comment: You mean at arrival/departure, for airports only, and are you expecting some specific rules forbidding it or whether agents would be told not to let drunk people go? And I assume you mean "visibly drunk".

Answer (score 7):

Not in a country where alcohol is banned or being drunk in public is an offense because in that scenario police at the airport may take you into custody.

I have seen a Srilankan national being deported back from India for being overly drunk and not being able to give satisfactory replies to the immigration officer.

Depends where you are going and which passport you hold because if you have a UK passport and land drunk at Heathrow they wont deport you anywhere :)

Comment: Yes I did observe a UK national, totally drunk, arrived from Bangladesh without his passport, lost it somewhere, and wasn't able to give replies also to the border official. They did a check on his citizenship and allowed him to enter after confirming he was a British national. But allowing you to board while drunk, not so sure.

Comment: I'm from Sri Lanka and I find this painfully relevant and true :). It's however the ability to answer the questions. Immigration officers have to identify you. I don't think they'll refuse your entry because you are drunk. Not answering their questions is a different issue though.

Comment: In Saudi Arabia, you'll be jailed, fined and then deported if you are visibly intoxicated. In Kuwait you'll be jailed (possibly fined) but allowed entry. If you cannot understand or comply with the crew's instructions, you may be deplaned and if you are inebriated during flight you'll be denied more drinks and if you are an annoyance to others or the crew, you will be restrained.